# How can I retrieve not except NULL with GROUP_CONCAT in query builder in symfony?

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, query-builder

In symfony, I join table user(id, email) and table useCases(id, userId, caseType) (relations is OneToMany) like this:

```
public function getQueryBuilder()
    {
        $qb = $this->userRepository->createQueryBuilder('u');
        $qb->select(
            '
                u.id,
                u.email,
                GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(CONCAT(IFNULL(uc.caseType,"NULL")))) as dfCaseType,
                
            '
        )
            ->leftJoin('u.userCases', 'uc')
            ->orderBy("u.id", "DESC");

        return $qb;
    }

public function getById($id)
    {
        $qb = $this->getQueryBuilder()
            ->where('u.id = :id')
            ->setParameter('id', $id);
        $result = $qb->groupBy('u.id')->setMaxResults(1)->getQuery()->getOneOrNullResult();
        return $result;
    }
```

I test query on Sequel Pro, and it's OK, here is query:

```
select user.id, user.email, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(CONCAT(IFNULL(`caseType`,'NULL')))) as dfCaseType from user, userCases where  user.id = userCases.userId AND user.id = 44613
```

and here is result:

```
id   emai               dfCaseType
1   aaa@gmail.com.       0,1,2,3,NULL
```

But when I apply in project symfony with query builder , it error :

```
[Syntax Error] line 0, col 231: Error: Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_IDENTIFIER, got '('
```

Please help me,  thanks!

Comment: I don't know how sensitive the query builder is but it's a lot of spaces before the sql-string starts: $qb->select(
            '
                u.id

Comment: DISTINCT is NOT a function but a keyword. Hence the `(` after it is wrong and should be replaced by a space. (obviously, the matching `)` must be removed too)